# System.IndexOutOfRangeException Sum of sums 0

Tags: c#

I'm sorry for this simple question.But i'm beginner.
I'm try to finds those subsets whose sum is 0 which numbers are in an array.

What is wrong with my subset.Length.I have debuged it i think logic is fine.But every time a took `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`. I tried `subset.Length-1`. Result didn't changed.

The exception is given in `if (subset[m] == 0)` statement's line.

Thanks.

```
 int[] subset={-3,-2,1,1,8} // the sum of -2, 1 and 1 is 0

for (int i = 0; i < subset.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; i < subset.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; i < subset.Length; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; i < subset.Length; l++)
                        {
                            for (int m = 0; i < subset.Length; m++)
                            {

                                if (subset[m] == 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The subset of sum of zero:{0}", subset[m]);
                                }
                                if (subset[l] + subset[m] == 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The subset of sum of zero:{0},{1}", subset[m], subset[l]);
                                }
                                if (subset[l] + subset[m] + subset[k] == 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The subset of sum of zero:{0},{1},{2}", subset[m], subset[l], subset[k]);
                                }
                                if (subset[l] + subset[m] + subset[k] + subset[j] == 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The subset of sum of zero:{0},{1},{2}", subset[m], subset[l], subset[k], subset[j]);
                                }

                                if (subset[l] + subset[m] + subset[k] + subset[j] + subset[i] == 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("The subset of sum of zero:{0},{1},{2},{3}", subset[m], subset[l], subset[k], subset[j], subset[i]);
                                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the logical mistake:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subset.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; i < subset.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; i < subset.Length; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; i < subset.Length; l++)
                        {
                            for (int m = 0; i < subset.Length; m++)
```

it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subset.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < subset.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < subset.Length; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < subset.Length; l++)
                        {
                            for (int m = 0; m < subset.Length; m++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note your conditions in the **for** loops: it is always `i < subset.Length`. But you should compare against the respective loop variables instead: **j**, **k**, **l** or **m**. (Copy'n'paste error?)

In your code, the **for** loops for j/k/l/m are infinite because **i** will never be incremented while these loops iterate...

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops terminating condition is always `i < subset.Length`, change it to relevant iteration variable, i.e. `for (int m = 0; m < subset.Length; m++)`

```
  for (int j = 0; j < subset.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < subset.Length; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < subset.Length; l++)
                    {
                        for (int m = 0; m < subset.Length; m++)
```

Comment: oops, rookie mistake :)

Comment: I missed that simple rule.Sorry That's my fault.
Thank you for your attention.